# How to create a function definition that takes in a value and returns true if contains any vowels?

Tags: javascript

I have an entrance exam about JavaScript. I am new to it and am stuck. I have no idea how to even tackle this question. My function definition has to meet this criteria for me to move forward.

Write a function definition named hasVowels that takes in value and returns true if the string contains any vowels.

```
assert(hasVowels("banana"), true, "Exercise 44");
assert(hasVowels("ubuntu"), true, "Exercise 44");
assert(hasVowels("QQQQ"), false, "Exercise 44");
assert(hasVowels("wyrd"), false, "Exercise 44");

function hasVowels(a,e,i,o,u) {
  return (a, e, i, o, u);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following implementation

```js
assert(hasVowels("banana"), true, "Exercise 44");
assert(hasVowels("ubuntu"), true, "Exercise 44");
assert(hasVowels("QQQQ"), false, "Exercise 44");
assert(hasVowels("wyrd"), false, "Exercise 44");

function hasVowels(s) {
  const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
  for (let vowel of vowels){
    if(s.includes(vowel.toLoweCase()) || s.includes(vowel.toUpperCase())) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Using 'return' inside the forEach will not set the return value of the function. If you fix the typo (missing 'r' in toLowerCase, and you have a 'l' instead of semicolon), then test you will see it never returns true.